# How to take an arbitrary screenshot/image and tilt it and apply bokeh/blurring to it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I would like to take a screenshot like the linked image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmAoc.jpg) and tilt it to the right or left a little and make it look like I did a bokeh-style blur photograph of the screen rather than taking a screenshot.

Wondering how to do that using some free program or if it's not possible to do online for free like with some vector/raster editor, then how to do it with photoshop or sketch or illustrator type thing.

Basically I would just like to make it look like I have a bokeh effect photograph of the screen, without having to actually whip out the DSLR. If it's not possible to do nicely that would be good to know too.

Comment: You'd probably need to use a  image editing software if you need to transform a screenshot into something like that... At least I'm not aware of like a tool specifically built for that. But if you can go from code to a screenshot, then you should try [**Marmoset**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/marmoset/npkfpddkpefnmkflhhligbkofhnafieb). And if you're not married to he idea of it being a perspective shot, then maybe check out: [Carbon web app](https://carbon.now.sh) and [Polacode plugin for VSC](https://github.com/octref/polacode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an authentic result if you have a good camera and you take a photo of a screen. To get bokeh you must have a lens with long enough focal length and big aperture. With low quality camera the result can be too bad. You can also get an unwanted moire pattern because the screen and the image are both made of pixels. The task isn't so trivial as it at first seems to be.

Artificial tilted view and bokeh can be made in Photoshop. You must insert  the needed spare white space or computer screen frame under your screenshot before you make other things. I handle here only a screenshot.

Distort your image to create artificial perspective:

[image]

Insert a layer mask, put there a BW gradient. Photoshop's Lens Blur needs it as blurring map. Black means no blur and white means max blur (= the set blur radius).

[image]

You must disable the layer mask to get rid of the transparency after filtering:

[image]

As you see, the edges are also blurry. It's very difficult to insert anything to the image in this phase. The possible screen frame should be in the image before blurring.

If the screen has non-matte surface, it reflects environment. You can simulate it by adding a low opacity layer which contains something in the room. The inserted reflection must be blurry also in the sharp area of the screenshot, because the reflected environment is distant.

Not asked: You can get something like this quite easily as long as you keep the resolution low:

[image]